Problems starting a project with thirdweb3
When I try to install thirdweb in Visula Studico Code with windowsWSL, I'm having some issues.
The command runned it was npx thirdweb@latest create --contract.
The terminal pops up with that:
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@walletconnect/auth-client'
Require stack:
- /home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@walletconnect/web3wallet/dist/index.cjs.js
- /home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/wallets/dist/thirdweb-dev-wallets.cjs.dev.js
- /home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/wallets/dist/thirdweb-dev-wallets.cjs.js
- /home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/auth/dist/auth-1db3810e.cjs.dev.js
- /home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/auth/dist/thirdweb-dev-auth.cjs.dev.js
- /home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/auth/dist/thirdweb-dev-auth.cjs.js
- /home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/cli/dist/cli/index.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1140:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:177:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@walletconnect/web3wallet/dist/index.cjs.js:1:75)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1364:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1422:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1203:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1019:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@walletconnect/web3wallet/dist/index.cjs.js',
    '/home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/wallets/dist/thirdweb-dev-wallets.cjs.dev.js',
    '/home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/wallets/dist/thirdweb-dev-wallets.cjs.js',
    '/home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/auth/dist/auth-1db3810e.cjs.dev.js',
    '/home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/auth/dist/thirdweb-dev-auth.cjs.dev.js',
    '/home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/auth/dist/thirdweb-dev-auth.cjs.js',
    '/home/seekeye/.npm/_npx/1b718c59dfba7034/node_modules/@thirdweb-dev/cli/dist/cli/index.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.20.2

Also, I tried the command npx thirdweb install and others command that specifies they webpage, but nothing fix the issue- Im a newbie, somebody out there can help me please?
Big Thanks.
npx thirdweb@latest create --contract
npx thirdweb install
npm i -S @walletconnect/sign-client
npm install -g npm

If you already have a project (with a package.json) and want to install thirdweb in it, use npx thirdweb install, otherwise use npx thirdweb create.
I've just tried both npx thirdweb create and npx thirdweb create --contract and both work fine:
npx thirdweb create --contract

    $$\     $$\       $$\                 $$\                         $$\       
    $$ |    $$ |      \__|                $$ |                        $$ |      
  $$$$$$\   $$$$$$$\  $$\  $$$$$$\   $$$$$$$ |$$\  $$\  $$\  $$$$$$\  $$$$$$$\  
  \_$$  _|  $$  __$$\ $$ |$$  __$$\ $$  __$$ |$$ | $$ | $$ |$$  __$$\ $$  __$$\ 
    $$ |    $$ |  $$ |$$ |$$ |  \__|$$ /  $$ |$$ | $$ | $$ |$$$$$$$$ |$$ |  $$ |
    $$ |$$\ $$ |  $$ |$$ |$$ |      $$ |  $$ |$$ | $$ | $$ |$$   ____|$$ |  $$ |
    \$$$$  |$$ |  $$ |$$ |$$ |      \$$$$$$$ |\$$$$$\$$$$  |\$$$$$$$\ $$$$$$$  |
    \____/ \__|  \__|\__|\__|       \_______| \_____\____/  \_______|\_______/ 

 thirdweb v0.13.80 

✔ What is your project named? … thirdweb-contracts
✔ What framework do you want to use? › Hardhat
✔ What will be the name of your new smart contract? … MyContract
✔ What type of contract do you want to start from? › Empty Contract
Creating a new thirdweb contracts project in /.../thirdweb-contracts.

Downloading files. This might take a moment.
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.

...

Success! Created thirdweb-contracts at /.../thirdweb-contracts

There's been some issues with past versions, but I'm not sure what version was the latest when you tried, so try with npx thirdweb@0.13.80 create.
Otherwise, it might be a local issue with NPM. Try:
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm cache clear --force
npm install
npx thirdweb create

